# How to auto update database according to dates in phpmyadmin and php?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am building an e-learning system where there is a table called "OfferedCourses" having attributes courseID, OfferDate, EndDate and Status. Something like this:-

```
courseID |  OfferDate | EndDate    | Status 
   2     | 24-12-2019 | 28-12-2019 | In Progress
```

Now I want my Application or Database to **auto change** the **Status** from "**In Progress**" to "**Not Available**" when 29-12-2019 starts(After End Date). Like auto-updation of the value. How can I achieve this in phpmyadmin mysql database? I am inserting the courseID, OfferDate, EndDate and Status from PHP Application through form.

Looking forward to your response, please reply complete details.

Comment: There's nothing to do/change. Any SELECT query can easily accommodate the condition. Indeed, if this is the only purpose of the status column, then that column is redundant.

Comment: You can try with using cronjob. In cronjob you should create a php script and run whenever you want to update the db.

Comment: @Strawberry  I want it to be independent from application. Its like the column gets auto update on 29-12-2019 at 00:00 AM without any interference from the application. like any sql event or trigger or procedure ?

Comment: @Strawberry explain a bit please. What i want is to make database auto update the column after the date expires without any intervention from Application or through any database query.

Comment: Use the MySQL Event Scheduler. Run a query every day that updates the `Status` column.

Comment: @Barmar can you tell me how to and what query to run

Comment: Here's the documentation on the event scheduler: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: It's a trivial `UPDATE` query, comparing `OfferDate` to `CURRENT_DATE()`.

Comment: It's an entirely redundant exercise